# What does !vi mean?

Tags: shell

I'm watching a video course on bash programming and the lecturer is constantly switching back and forth between his instance of the vi text editor and the command line by exiting out of vi and coming back in using this command: `!vi`. What I'm able to infer from this is that it probably means open vi along with the last file that was in the process of editing before vi was closed, but when I try doing that in my command line, that's not what happens. Vi just opens up with its welcome message.

Comment: Perhaps better placed in superuser so?

Comment: History expansion in shell: the most recent command starting with `vi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash, `!vi` expands to the most recent command starting with `"vi"`. See  [History Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) in the Bash manual.